# Is there a way to select layers via relative reference (eg. "Next Layer" instead of "Layer X")?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

While scheming actions, sometimes i find myself in a situation where i work with multiple layer copies going back and forth through them, and sometimes i cant rely on their names, since i design some actions to be used in many types of repetitive tasks on my works (from game assets to ground floor plans) that not always have the same structure of name/order.

There is a way to call out a script command that when triggered on the action list will select the layer immediately above (or below) the current layer it is being worked?

If so, i can call a single line or short string of command independently or i must have it saved somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the shortcut when recording your action there Photoshop has four shortcuts for relatively, targeting visible layer. Note layers with their visibility off will be skipped. It is hard to turn off and on a layers visibility in an action.  To target a layer  with its visibility off you need to use its name and Photoshop does not require layer names to be unique.  I have no idea if there are duplicate layer names which layer would be targeted.
Alt+, Target bottom visible layer 
Alt+. Target top visible layer 
Alt+[ Target next visible layer backward 
Alt+] Target next visible layer forward